# PyhtonError ImportError: No module named six

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-requests

I am running Python 2.7.13 on  Windows 7, and I got this error:

```
ImportError: No module named six
```

But I found six.py and six.pyc in "C:\Python27\Lib\site-package\pip\_vendor\six.py", ""C:\Python27\Lib\site-package\pip\_vendor\six.pyc".

1. Can I copy this file six.py into my project? Or I must download and install the module named six？
2. What function does six.py or module named six have？

Comment: Is python added to  environment variable?

Comment: @HariomSingh Oh I forgot to do this, and now it worked. Thanks~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run to make sure if six is properly installed or not,

```
pip install six
```

if output says module is already installed and still the problem persists then you can visit and download the wheel file of six module from the link : https://pypi.python.org/pypi/six

To install wheel file again method is same:

```
pip install wheel_file_name.whl
```

Yes, you can install six into a python project and for that you don't have to copy the .py or .pyc file of six, for that you have to create a virtual enviroment in the project, follow this link on how to create and manage a virtual environment for python project in windows : http://pymote.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install/windows_virtualenv.html